# get pdf cordinates for text extraction

Tags: pdf, ocr, pdftotext

I am using pdftotext for extracting text at certain parts of PDF but finding the
x, y and W and H cordinate locations is very difficult. I am unsure whether there are tools to do that.

I have tried importing pdf to inkscape and gimp but the cordinates values have no correspondence in them to those of PDFTOTEXT values.

Please suggest me a good open source program/utility to find the cordinates / layouts

```
pdftotext -f 3 -l 3 -x 205 -y 40 -W 180 -H 75 -layout input.pdf - | sed 's/\(.*\)/\"\1\"/g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: Typically, measurements in a PDF are in points, with (0,0) at the lower left corner.

Comment: how to get them with the tools you know?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "find the coordinates".  Usually, it's better to extract ALL the text from a PDF and use context clues to pick out the parts you want.

Comment: We need to look for a specifc text at certain parts of the pdf. so i need a tool that provides me coordinate locations.

Comment: `pdfminer` can do this.  It can return to you a list of "objects", including their size and positions.